# block a printer on a ubiquiti network from guest users

Tags: printer, ubiquiti, guest

trying to block a printer on a ubiquiti network with 3 lans: One is Public or Guest(open) and two are p/w protected.

Will a network rule work or should I use vlans? Having trouble with network rules

Answer (score 0):

I think separate vlans will work.

I am also using ubiquiti and I use the simpler approach of using a different subnet for guest connections.  That way its robust and I dont have to keep protecting additional devices.

Comment: That's a very straightforward approach, I like it. Thank you.